# Error creating directory from the name of current logged in user inside App_Data folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-identity

In controller:

```
 var UserName = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
  string  Path1 = "~/App_Data/Upload/" + UserName; 

  if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(Path1)))
            {
            DirectoryInfo di =      Directory.CreateDirectory(UserName);
             }
```

But it gives an error:

An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Access to the path 'abc@abc.com' is denied.

I have registered one user as abc@abc.com

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if `Server.MapPath(Path1)` directory exists and you are trying to create `UserName` directory!

```
var userName = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
string path1 = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Upload/" + userName); 

if (!Directory.Exists(path1))
{
     DirectoryInfo di =  Directory.CreateDirectory(path1);
}
```

**Edit**

Also try give [network service permissions](http://mmmsoftware.blogspot.gr/2013/01/adding-network-service-account-to.html).

Comment: I want to create the directory of the same name as user name. Ex. Suppose I have a user account with 'abc' name then directory's name should be abc as well

Comment: You do not want that directory to be inside App_Data folder of your project?

Comment: I want it inside that folder, yup. I am behaving like moron? Sorry but I am getting what's my mistake. :(

Comment: I tried to change as you said and I got error " An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Access to the path '~/App_Data/Upload/q@a.c' is denied. "

Comment: @Nil maybe network services does not have permission. check link on how to manage that

Comment: I am unable to find link :(